# Website show as many images as are in the directory

Tags: javascript, html, loops

I want to create HTML website, which will show as many images as are in the directory.
There can be 5 or can be 100. 
By clicking NEXT/ PREVIOUS button, website should show single image from directory.

```
        $(document).ready(function () {

            var images = [
                "Icons/1.PNG",
                "Icons/2.PNG",
                "Icons/3.PNG"
            ];

            var imageIndex = 0,
                iLength = images.length - 1,
                imageEl = $('#image'),
                prevEl = $('#previous'),
                nextEl = $('#hoger');

            prevEl.on("click", function () {
                imageIndex--;

                imageEl.attr('src', images[imageIndex]);

                nextEl.prop('disabled', false);
                prevEl.prop('disabled', !imageIndex);
            });

            nextEl.on("click", function () {
                imageIndex++;

                imageEl.attr('src', images[imageIndex]);

                nextEl.prop('disabled', imageIndex === iLength);
                prevEl.prop('disabled', false);
            });

            prevEl.prop('disabled', true);
            imageEl.attr(images[0]);
        });
    </script>
```

Instead of list images in `var = images`, I would need to read count of images.

Comment: You either need to send down all the images at the beginning, send down a total image count  and request them one by one, or have the server do the stepping through. Local JS doesn't know how many images there are in the directory.

Comment: Yeah, as @DBS said, you need to use your server to do this. Although _technically_ you can do it by starting at 1, and then iteratively trying to load the next image in the sequence until you get a 404, but it's messy. What server / platform are you using @cloudy?

Comment: I used Azure App Service to host the website. Pipeline deploy App Service with new uploaded images to the Repo. So i want to just be proactive and handle all images.

Comment: What software are you using on Azure? PHP, Java, Python, Node....

Comment: I selected .Net v4.7, but i can change anytime.

Comment: Is possible to setup variables ```var images = [] ``` able to read from external txt file?
I would create pipeline which will update txt file with the all names of images.